# How to show all available images in WP's media library when using the Polylang plugin?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, plugin-polylang

It seems that depending on which default language I've set Polylang to, all my uploaded images are isolated so that I can only pick them when I'm editing posts in the default language.

I have a lot more images shared/in-common between English and French posts than images specific to a single language.

Is there any option to show all images regardless of which language I'm currently editing in Wordpress?

[image]

It's very likely I might of just uploaded them in the media library when I was currently editing a post (in which case, maybe it isolates the images to be available only for that particular language & given post?) if so, I may have an entirely different problem on my hands.

Is there a way to simply show ALL assets?

Comment: Support is pretty good on https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/polylang, have you tried asking there? Show all languages usually removes the filters in the backend. If you're looking for a file try the search field and maybe you're correct that it didn't attach to a post.

Comment: Just found the answer actually, will post it up in a sec.

Comment: Oh, and actually this seems to be a duplicate! My bad... [EDIT] However it exists on stackoverflow (not the WP stackexchange) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753339/wordpress-media-library-issue-with-polylang-plugin, so I wonder if I can repost the answer?

Comment: Noting that while this and other 3rd party plugin questions are off-topic, I've locked it as it has lots of upvotes and views. Users of Polylang should use the official support routes or ask in Polylang communities

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From this post at [wordpress.org/support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/polylang-makes-media-vanish-in-library#post-6514430), the user **Chrystl** points out:

> If don't need to translate your media titles, uncheck this option:
>
> In **Languages > Settings tab > Media: "Activate languages and translations for media"**.
>
> And you will access to your ***entire library*** by clicking on "Add media" and "Set featured image".

And that indeed did the trick for me! :)